# Building wheel for psycopg2 ... error pip3 install psycopg2?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, requirements.txt

When I'm running

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

then show me errors I show you bellow
I'm using

```
python version 3.8

PostgreSQL 13.0 (Ubuntu 13.0-1.pgdg20.04+1)
```

see my requirement.txt files here

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
croniter==0.3.24
Django==2.0.5
django-rq==1.1.0
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
idna==2.7
jdcal==1.4
lxml==4.2.3
openpyxl==2.5.4
#pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-decouple==3.1
pytz==2018.5
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.19.1
rq==0.12.0
rq-scheduler==0.8.3
six==1.11.0
Unipath==1.1
urllib3==1.23
```

so show me this error in terminal I share with you complete command message that i typed already

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt                                               ✔  2186  17:28:42
Requirement already satisfied: certifi==2018.4.16 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (2018.4.16)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==3.0.4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: click==6.7 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: croniter==0.3.24 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (0.3.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Django==2.0.5 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: django-rq==1.1.0 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile==1.0.1 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna==2.7 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: jdcal==1.4 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml==4.2.3 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (4.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl==2.5.4 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (2.5.4)
Collecting psycopg2==2.7.5
  Using cached psycopg2-2.7.5.tar.gz (426 kB)
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
  Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.8.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.0 MB 101 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil==2.7.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) (2.7.3)
Processing /code/data/.cache/pip/wheels/34/e3/10/a284f71c3b99a9ed3ab3d7d6f3af2dd72855bf04aa763dfef5/python_decouple-3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz==2018.5 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 17)) (2018.5)
Collecting redis==2.10.6
  Using cached redis-2.10.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting requests==2.19.1
  Using cached requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Collecting rq==0.12.0
  Using cached rq-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Collecting rq-scheduler==0.8.3
  Using cached rq_scheduler-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting six==1.11.0
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Unipath==1.1 in /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 23)) (1.1)
Collecting urllib3==1.23
  Using cached urllib3-1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wg77t_ou/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"
 command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wg77t_ou/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wg77t_ou/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-_y3ne80g
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wg77t_ou/psycopg2/
  Complete output (72 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_async_keyword.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_replication.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_errcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_fast_executemany.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
  Skipping optional fixer: buffer
  Skipping optional fixer: idioms
  Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/13/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
  psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_is_main_interp’:
  psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:689:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState’ {aka ‘struct _is’}
    689 |     while (interp->next)
        |                  ^~
  
  It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
  
  You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
  If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
  required for the build and try again.
  
  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
  
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2, psycopg2-binary, python-decouple, redis, urllib3, requests, rq, rq-scheduler, six
  Attempting uninstall: psycopg2
    Found existing installation: psycopg2 2.8.6
    Uninstalling psycopg2-2.8.6:
      Successfully uninstalled psycopg2-2.8.6
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wg77t_ou/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wg77t_ou/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8sijq8ua/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /code/data/.local/include/python3.8/psycopg2
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wg77t_ou/psycopg2/
    Complete output (72 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_async_keyword.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_replication.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_errcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_fast_executemany.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.7.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/13/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_is_main_interp’:
    psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:689:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState’ {aka ‘struct _is’}
      689 |     while (interp->next)
          |                  ^~
    
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
    
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of psycopg2
  Moving to /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2-2.8.6-py3.8.egg-info
   from /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~sycopg2-2.8.6-py3.8.egg-info
  Moving to /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/
   from /code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~sycopg2
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wg77t_ou/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wg77t_ou/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8sijq8ua/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /code/data/.local/include/python3.8/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

from requirement.txt

```
#psycopg2==2.7.5
#psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
```

when I comment above then error is gone but absolutely database not work properly then.
but if I try python3 manage.py runserver
then show me also error

```
 from lawyers.views import *
  File "/code/data/abc/proj/lawyers/views.py", line 37, in <module>
    from django_rq import job
  File "/code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_rq/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .decorators import job
  File "/code/data/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_rq/decorators.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .queues import get_queue
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (queues.py, line 132)
```

I think error show me in **django_rq**
when type python3 manage.py runserver
tell me the possible solutions thank you I try many but unsuccessful

Comment: Just leave `psycopg2==2.7.5` commented out. Uncomment `psycopg2-binary==2.8.5`. The binary version does not need the development libraries to be installed. The error you got had to do with trying to build `psycopg2==2.7.5` from source and not having the development libraries. Also your install indicated you already had psycopg2 2.8.6 installed, so I would bump the version in your requirements. It also would probably not hurt to uninstall psycopg2 before running the above again, to make sure you are only working with one version.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver show me again same error when try to run python3 manage.py runserver then show me invalid syntax error from django-rq package 

/python3.8/site-packages/django_rq/decorators.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .queues import get_queue
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (queues.py, line 132)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem work for me
basically issue also with python
version I install python version **3.7** by using this command

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

then activate environment

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Then I install my **requirements.txt** files by using this command

```
 python3.7 -m pip install requirements.txt
```

my this error resolved not show me again
**Building wheel for psycopg2 … error pip3 install psycopg2?**

then show me

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'**
then I install using this way

```
python3.7 -m pip install pandas
```

When I run `python3.7 manage.py runserver`
Then show me error is `django-rq`

```
/code/data/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_rq/queues.py", line 132
    def get_queue(name='default', default_timeout=None, async=None,
                                                            ^
```

I this so async is reserved word now in python then in my package  I replace the name of `async` to `is_async`  in whole `django-rq/queues.py`
when I run project again then show me this error

```
  import xlsxwriter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
```

Then I fix by this way

```
 python3.7 -m pip install xlsxwriter
```

Then show me one more error

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Then I fixed using this way

```
python3.7 -m pip install bs4
```

Then my project work fine.
I hope my solution is helpful for anyone.
I have require temporarily python3.7 version so I'm not wanted to change their path to python3 .